# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid cursor position

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

I created a simple application which lets users purchase Tickets. However, I have run into this error whenever I try to purchase "n" number of tickets. Now, I know that you need the `crs.next()` statement while operating with databases, I have used it a number of times but for some reason it doesn't work here. It gives me the **java.sql.SQLException: Invalid cursor position** error.

This is my code snippet for inserting a ticket.

```
public void buyTicket(int id,int n,int price) throws SQLException{

    crs.setCommand("SELECT PAYID FROM PAYMENTINFO WHERE ACCOUNT = '"+2134541+"'");
    crs.execute();
    crs.next();
    payID = crs.getInt("PAYID");
    
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        
    crs.setCommand("Insert into Tickets (TicketType,EventID,UserID,PayID,Price) values ("+false+","+id+
            ","+ loginBean.getuID() + ","+payID+","+price+")");
    
    crs.execute();
    crs.next();
    }

    crs.setCommand("UPDATE EVENTS SET MAXTICKETS = MAXTICKETS - "+n+"WHERE EVENTID = "+eb.getEventID());
    crs.execute();
    crs.next();
   
}
```

The problem occurs inside the `for loop`.The `payID` is set and using the `payID` I try to insert into the Ticket table. If I place a breakpoint at the `crs.next()` statement, the data is entered. Without it, it gives me the exception. Thank you for your help

**CRS INITIALIZATION**

CachedRowSet crs = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet();

```
    crs.setUrl("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Events Ticket Management");

    crs.setUsername("x");

    crs.setPassword("x");
```

**UPDATE**

After placing the `INSERT` statement in a `try-catch` block, the tickets are entered into the database, however the update crashes now, giving a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Comment: What is `crs` -- could you add in the code for this variable's declaration? Looks like you're re-using the same `Statement` for `SELECT`, `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, which is probably causing the problem.

Comment: @MickMnemonic crs is a CachedRowSet type variable.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Also, its 3AM here. Is it okay if I post the code after I wake up?

Comment: Yes, it's perfecly okay for me if you only post code while awake. :)

Comment: @MickMnemonic Thank you! I'll tag you once I post it. Thank you for your precious time :)

Comment: What are you expecting next() to do after an insert or update?

Comment: @MarkLeiber I guess to move to the next row to insert or update a new result? I have done the same for registration,i.e. insert new data when a user registers, but here it seems to fail.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Added the declaration!

Comment: @MickMnemonic Well, I thought it worked but it just catches the exception after iterating once in the for loop. Hence only 2 tickets get inserted.

Comment: Got it now, the crs.next() was making the error. I should probably make it a habit to read the documentation first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method works as a temporary fix as the exception is caught. This doesn't let me set "n" number of tickets and only 2 tickets! Also it was giving a java.lang.NullPointerException because I wasn't setting `ID` to `eventID`. That was kind of sloppy from my side.

```
   public void buyTicket(int id,int n,int price) throws SQLException{
    crs.setCommand("SELECT PAYID FROM PAYMENTINFO WHERE ACCOUNT = '"+account+"'");
    crs.execute();
    crs.next();
    payID = crs.getInt("PAYID");

    try{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

    crs.setCommand("Insert into Tickets (TicketType,EventID,UserID,PayID,Price) values ("+false+","+id+
            ","+ loginBean.getuID() + ","+payID+","+price+")");

    crs.execute();
    crs.next();


    }
    }
    catch(SQLException e){

    System.out.println("  Message:    " + e.getMessage());
    e = e.getNextException();}

    try{
    crs.setCommand("UPDATE EVENTS SET MAXTICKETS = MAXTICKETS - "+n+"WHERE EVENTID = "+id);
    crs.execute();
    crs.next();
    }
    catch(SQLException e ){

    System.out.println("  Message:    " + e.getMessage());
    e = e.getNextException();
    }


}
```